# AngularDART color picker

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I'm trying to have colorpicker in AngularDART code:

I wrote this statement, but the {{myColor}} is not updated if the color is changed!

```
<input type="color" ng-model="myColor" value="#FFFFFF"/> 
     {{myColor}}
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you please add a bit more code? How does your controller look like? What Angular version are you using?

Comment: Hi @GünterZöchbauer, nothing special in the code, I wrote simple controller as I'm in the learning stage, the same code with type="text" worked perfectly with me, same with type="date", but with type="color" nothing is dispalyed!

Comment: I saw a few weeks discussions or commits about `input type='color'` support in Angular. Maybe this isn't finished yet or hasn't landed in the current release yet.

Comment: thanks a lot, then I've to wait little bit fro new AngularDART edition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same code worked perfectly with DART SDK 1.6.0.

```
<input type="color" ng-model="myColor" value="#FFFFFF"/> 
 {{myColor}}
```